# Android lollipop error code -505 during installation app

Tags: android, installation

I have a nexus 9 with android lollipop but I get the error code -505 trying to install some apps from the Play Store.

These apps are:

- asphalt 8
- dungeon hunter 4
- six guns; and
- other gameloft game

Other apps works install fine but these games don't.

Can you tell me what this error code means? Can you suggest to me how I can fix it?

Comment: Had you upgraded your phone to lollipop, or its factory installed.? its a known bug, try upgrading your phone, it might fix it.

Comment: my device is nexus 9 and i bought it with android lollipop installed...not ugrade it myself

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me guess - you your apps were made with adobe air?

It's a bug google introduced with lollipop. Its related to the SHA1 generation from some certificates.

See:

- http://www.zdnet.com/android-lollipop-users-warn-of-unusable-devices-after-upgrading-7000035977/
- https://forums.adobe.com/message/6942812#6942812
- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?d=79089
- https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1668
- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79375

There is basically no solution except to wait for google to fix it or re-sign your app with a different key. But then you can't update it in the play store either.

If the app was installed on your device *before* the lollipop update, but is now gone, a workaround might be to uninstall the app using `adb uninstall` and then install it again.

**update**: As far as I know this is partially fixed in Android 5.0.1 and completely fixed in 5.0.2

Comment: still having the issue with 5.1.1 :(

Answer (score 7):

I also had this issue. I was releasing *Sandbox* and *Production* (different Android Flavors) apps with different package names, but same GCM permissions.

I started using `${packageName}` in ***AndroidManifest.xml*** file.

I changed from

```
<!-- GCM specific permissions -->
<permission
    android:name="com.playgong.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.playgong.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
```

to

```
<!-- GCM specific permissions -->
<permission
    android:name="${packageName}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="${packageName}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
```

And in *receiver's **intent-filter*** from:

```
<category android:name="com.playgong"/>
```

to:

```
<category android:name="${packageName}"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

I must say if you have more accounts in lollipop you must once uninstall from all user. Means go to settings - app - in your app on settings icon delete from all user is an option click on that an install again.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to install the App again if you follow the answers on this post about uninstalling Apps for all users on Android 5.0 Lollipop:

[INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION... C2D_MESSAGE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043933/install-failed-duplicate-permission-c2d-message)

Answer (score 1):

I received this error when attempting to install Pure Calendar widget. Logcat showed that my GTasks app already had permission to read tasks. Apparently under 5.0 there can be only one. I uninstalled GTasks and Pure Calendar widget installed fine. I the attempted to reinstall GTasks and got the same error with similar results in logcat.
Apparently Google has made it so only one app can have a specific permission. This will be VERY limiting if they don't fix it.