# When installing app from google play getting error code -505

Tags: android

I have generated 3 different apps with different key store and with different package name from  android studio and published on google play store. When one app is installed and try to install second app or third app i get google play installation error. I am not sure what i am doing wrong here. As my keystore and packages are different. Done lots of RND but did not find any solution. Please help me out here. Also find attached error code screen shot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WStz6.jpg)

Comment: this looks similar ? http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88214/how-do-i-deal-with-unknown-installation-error-code-505

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android lollipop error code -505 during installation app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27041575/android-lollipop-error-code-505-during-installation-app)

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem. Actually problem was accruing due to same permission in manifest of all of the 3 apps. I was not using project package name in the permissions. So when i install one app then try to install second app then permission mismatch problem was accruing. Once i have given package name in permission it start working fine. Before is was using :-

```
<permission
        android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Then i convert this code by following code :-

```
<permission
        android:name="APP_PACKAGE_NAME.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="APP_PACKAGE_NAME.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
```

This resolved my problem.